# iptables marks are being ignored by tc?

Tags: iptables, raspberry-pi, qos

I'm getting crazy with this one:

```
tc qdisc add dev $WANCARD root handle 1: htb default 1
tc class add dev $WANCARD parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate $SPEED burst 6k prio 1 
tc class add dev $WANCARD parent 1: classid 1:2 htb rate $SPEED burst 6k prio 2
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -d $LOCALNET -p tcp --sport 563 -j LOG  --log-prefix '* usenet *' --log-level 4
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -d $LOCALNET -p tcp --sport 563 -j MARK --set-mark 2 # -m comment --comment "usenet download"
iptables -t mangle -A FORWARD -d $LOCALNET -p tcp --sport 563 -j LOG  --log-prefix '* usenet *' --log-level 4
tc filter add dev $WANCARD parent 1: prio 2 protocol ip handle 2 fw flowid 1:2
```

according to my log the mark changes as it should, but everything is still handled by 1:1 according to

```
tc -s class show dev $WANCARD
```

instead of MARK CLASSIFY would be fine as well

```
-j CLASSIFY --set-class 1:2
```

but results in

```
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

what is it i don't see here? (in case it matters: i'm using raspbian stretch)

thank you in advance

Comment: Look at this [PDF document also talking about TC / netfilter interactions](https://people.netfilter.org/pablo/netdev0.1/papers/Linux-Traffic-Control-Classifier-Action-Subsystem-Architecture.pdf). I'm not sure iptables can alter ingress, because it's too late. Perhaps there are some tricks (interfaces type ifb maybe?). I don't have real knowledge here. As for CLASSIFY, most probably it wasn't compiled in your kernel

Comment: An useful link: [wondershaper 1.4](https://github.com/magnific0/wondershaper). It doesn't use iptables at all but can filter upon source ports (with a match filter directly in tc)

Comment: It seems that the CLASSIFY target is only valid in the POSTROUTING chain of the mangle table.

Comment: As surprising as it can seem tc can use conntrack's connmark (by searching itself the conntrack table). So there should be hope to connmark outgoing packets/flows, and work on the incoming packet's connmark: https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/iproute2/tc-connmark.8.en.html (but that's overkill to match a fixed port)